# Disable "It looks like you are typing while in full screen" popup

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

iOS 12 has a new feature where if you're in full screen in Safari, if you tap or swipe repeatedly, you get a popup that says "It looks like you are typing in full screen. Typing is not allowed in full screen videos. "[url]" may be showing a fake keyboard to trick you into disclosing personal or financial information."

Is there a setting to disable this? It often pops up when I'm just scrubbing a video or scrolling through a document, and I've seen this message enough to be aware of that.

[Related question from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53480608/can-i-suppress-alert-it-looks-like-you-are-typing-while-in-full-screen-over-io)

[image: Screenshot of dialog]
(image from u/p_giguere1 from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/9m94qg/til_safari_on_ios_12_has_builtin_protection/))